# MapBasic centroid in EPSG:28354

Tags: coordinate-system, mapinfo, mapbasic

I have a table in MG94 Z 54 (EPSG:28354).

My MapBasic statement is

```
Commit Table DCDB As "C:\DCDB_Full_Copy.TAB" TYPE NATIVE Charset "WindowsLatin1" CoordSys Earth Projection 8, 116, "m", 141, 0, 0.9996, 500000, 10000000 Bounds (-7745844.29605, 2035.05684549) (8745844.29605, 19997964.9432) Interactive
Update DCDB_Full_Copy Set X = CentroidX(obj)
Update DCDB_Full_Copy Set Y = CentroidY(obj)
```

It gives me

> 22N14849 [LotPlan], 141.071716, -17.66865

but it should be

> 22N14849 [LotPlan], 507606.510877, 8046471.56601

How can I get the coordinates in the correct format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the coordinate system to use before extracting the coordinates from the object:

```
Commit Table DCDB As "C:\DCDB_Full_Copy.TAB" TYPE NATIVE Charset "WindowsLatin1" 
    CoordSys Earth Projection 8, 116, "m", 141, 0, 0.9996, 500000, 10000000 Bounds (-7745844.29605, 2035.05684549) (8745844.29605, 19997964.9432) Interactive

'**Assuming  you want to use the coordinate system of the table
Set CoordSys Table DCDB_Full_Copy

**You can do the update in one statement:
Update DCDB_Full_Copy 
   Set X = CentroidX(obj)
     , Y = CentroidY(obj)
```